# Signal decimator/down-sample with lowest propagation delay

Tags: counter, delay, timing, propagation, ripple-counter

I would like to frequency-divide a 10 MHz digital signal by a factor of 8 or 16, with the lowest possible propagation delay. I need a propagation delay that is at most 5-10 ns. The best solution I thought of is to simply use a flip-flop counter. [This seemed to be a good one](http://www.uni-kl.de/elektronik-lager/417668), but the propagation delay can go up to 70 ns in that chip!

Is there a chip that is better suited with my timing requirement? Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve this?

**More details if you're interested:**

The reason for all this is that I'm trying to use a 10 MHz signal to control an FTM counter in a microcontroller (Teensy 3.6) in input capture mode with some interrupt control used as a phase-lock to keep sync with the 10 MHz signal. The problem is that the FTM counter is not sensitive to that kind of very high frequency, so I need to frequency-divide it before using it.

Comment: When I hear "downsample", for me that means collecting and **averaging** a number of samples. For example 10 Msps @ 2 bit becomes 2.5 Msps at 4 bitThat means, there will inherently be a delay between the input signal and downsampled signal. If I'd downsample a 10 MHz (sample every 100 ns) signal then doing that \$n\$ times means \$n*100\$ ns delay. So I do not see how you could even get to that 5-10 ns.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What's the right word for skipping every `n` samples? That's what I mean with down-sample. There's actually no use in averaging a clock signal. There's no data there.

Comment: If there is no data then you should call it a **clock**. Do you want to divide (in frequency) that clock? For example: 10 MHz in, divide-by-4: 2.5 MHz out ? The propagation delay is then what you see on the timing of the edges between the input and output clock. 5 - 10 ns means a frequency divider that should be able to do more than 200 MHz.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes, exactly. I'll improve the question. Thanks for the idea of the relation to the bandwidth. I think that'll take me to the right direction. I'm searching now.

Comment: The 74LS90 from your link is **ancient**! Better have a look at the 74AC series CMOS logic, here are some: https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/search?filters=16587  Still, the total delay will still add up in 10s of nano-seconds. There are also **prescalers** designed for dividing frequencies. Not all will work with 10 MHz input though, most are designed for much higher frequencies, try here: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/32?keywords=prescaler&pkeyword=&v=

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 125 MHz? Not bad! Thanks!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I believe the correct term for skipping every n samples is decimation.